# Jssor Slider: How to target specific slide with text/image link?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jssor

Can anyone tell me how to target a particular slide using a simple text/image link?

Specifically, I am using the Jssor Slider Cluster (http://www.jssor.com/demos/slider-cluster.html).

Currently the slides can be navigated using Bullet Navigator and Arrow Navigator which are in standard dimension and/or spaced equally apart. I am attempting to create my own links which have different sizes/lengths.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways,

## 1. use api call to play to specified slide.

```
jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(2);
//or
jssor_slider1.$GoTo(2);
```

## 2. customize thumbnail navigator with your own format.

Please see 12 thumbnail navigator skins in the package.
Note that you can compose your thumbnail in any format (html, text, image or combination)