# Jssor Slider: How to target specific Child Slide

Tags: jquery, jssor

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/demos/grid-slider.html

Is there a way to target child slides, similar to this? [Jssor Slider: How to target specific slide with text/image link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229776/jssor-slider-how-to-target-specific-slide-with-text-image-link)

I am trying to make slides do a "mouseover slide" effect, but the codes I used didn't work:

```
$("#sliderh1_container").mouseenter(function(){
  jssor_slider1.child.$Play(1);
});

$("#sliderh1_container").mouseleave(function(){
  jssor_slider1.child.$Play(0);
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var nestedSliders = [];

        $.each(["sliderh1_container", "sliderh2_container", "sliderh3_container", "sliderh4_container"], function (index, value) {

            var sliderhOptions = {
                $PauseOnHover: 0,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 3
                $AutoPlaySteps: 4,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
                $SlideDuration: 300,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                $SlideWidth: 200,                                   //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                //$SlideHeight: 150,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 3,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                $Cols: 4,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $Align: 0,                              //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 0,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                    $Rows: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                    $SpacingX: 0,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 0,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                }
            }
            var jssor_sliderh = new $JssorSlider$(value, sliderhOptions);

            nestedSliders.push(jssor_sliderh);
        });

        $("#sliderh1_container").mouseenter(function () {
            nestedSliders[0].$Play();
        });

        $("#sliderh1_container").mouseleave(function () {
            nestedSliders[0].$Pause();
        });
```

Note that $PauseOnHover must be set to 0. Also, better set $AutoPlaySteps to 4