# How to use API call ( jssor_slider1.$GoTo(N))

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

Excuse me, can you help me to use the Api Call?

I am trying in this way, using the command to specify a slide but nothing happens.

Have patience. Newbie. Thanks

```
<script>
function toSlide(go){ jssor_slider1.$GoTo(go) }
</script>
```

Comment: What is `jssor_slider1`?

Comment: I read this answare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229776/jssor-slider-how-to-target-specific-slide-with-text-image-link

tanks oriol

Answer (score 0):

```
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
        jssor_slider1.$GoTo(3);
```

reference: http://www.jssor.com/testcase/api-play-pause-goto-playto-test.source.html