# jssor slider api call comes back undefined

Tags: javascript, slider, jssor

I'm trying to make an API call to the jssor slider like this.

```
jssor_slider1.$GoTo(5);
```

as this question suggests [Jssor Slider: How to target specific slide with text/image link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229776/jssor-slider-how-to-target-specific-slide-with-text-image-link)

My Chrome tools tell me jssor_slider1 is undefined even though the slider is working fine on the page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you call the api out of the scope of variable jssor_slider1.

Typically, variable jssor_slider1 is defined in a function scope. see following,

## 1. Incorrect api call

```
function(...)
{
    ...
    var jssor_slider1 = ...;
    ...
}
jssor_slider1.$GoTo(5);
```

## 2. Correct api call

```
function(...)
{
    ...
    var jssor_slider1 = ...;
    ...
    jssor_slider1.$GoTo(5);
    ...
}
```

Comment: That was it! I setup jssor_slider1 as global to access it in another script and everything is happy. Thanks.